# Different background for empty and filled EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to use different backgrounds in an `EditText` for when it is empty vs filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can subclass EditText indeed

```
public class MyEditText extends EditText {

    Drawable backgroundEmpty, backgroundFilled;

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs){
        if(attrs != null){
            backgroundEmpty = ...
            backgroundFilled = ...
        }else{
            backgroundEmpty = ...
            backgroundFilled = ... 
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
        setBackground(text.toString().length() == 0 ? backgroundEmpty : backgroundFilled);
    }
}
```

or use a TextWatcher

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        editText.setBackground(s.toString().length() == 0 ? backgroundEmpty : backgroundFilled);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can push your answer one step further and provide some xml code ^^.

Comment: For using the custom EditText.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Text Watcher and adding it to EditText.
Changing parents layout (backgroundColor property) within is not hard.

[Text Watcher Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Good luck. (Next time try to be more explanatory on your issue :))

Comment: I'd like to add: If you intend to have several of these, it might be worthwhile to subclass EditText and give this subclass a secondary background attribute, so this can be handled through the layout xml.

Comment: This can only be achieved if you started using 2-Way Databind Android. 
That is the only way XML layouts accept conditions. 
Please read more on: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#expression_language

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of implementing the conditions in the subclass code, and adding a attribute called, say, "secondarybackground" like in the [Creating a View Class](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) tutorial.

Comment: That way you would be having so much more trouble than making TextWatchers. 
Let me know if you need anything else :)